# How to find $a^{2033}+\frac{1}{a^{2033}}$ from the equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was Junior High School Student, please explain the answer like you teach a Junior High School Student

> Given :
> $$P(x) = 325^6+325^5+325^4+325^3+325^2+325+2345$$
>
> Given a number $a$, $P(a) = 2020$,
> Find $$a^{2033} + \frac{1}{a^{2033}}$$

I have
$P(a) = 2020$

$325a^6+325a^5+325a^4+325a^3+325a^2+325a+2345$ = $2020$

$325(a^6+a^5+a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1)=0$

divided by $a^3$, I get :

$a^3+a^2+a+1+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{a^3}=0$

$(a+\frac{1}{a})^3-3(a+\frac{1}{a})+(a+\frac{1}{a})^2-2+(a+\frac{1}{a})+1=0$

Suppose that $y=a+\frac{1}{a}$

$y^3+y^2-2y-1=0$, i'm stuck:)

Comment: welcome to MSE! please show what you have tried this helps users cater to your needs and avoids possible closing of question due to lack of context

Comment: Are you familiar with trigonometry?

Comment: @bjorn93 some the basics are yes,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(a^6+a^5+a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow (a-1)(a^6+a^5+a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1) = a^7-1 = 0$$

So $a^7 = 1$ and $a^{2033} = a^{7 \cdot 290 + 3} = a^3$, and therefore $\frac{1}{a^{2033}} = \frac{1}{a^3}$.

---

Since $a^7 = 1$, $a = e^{2 \pi k i / 7}$, where $k =1, 2, \cdots, 6$ (note that we exclude $k = 0$ as $a \ne 1$).

Therefore, the expression equals $e^{6 \pi k i /7} + e^{-6 \pi k i / 7} = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} (e^{6 \pi k i /7} + e^{-6 \pi k i / 7}) = 2 \cos(6 \pi k /7)$ since $\cos x = \frac{1}{2} (e^{ix} + e^{-ix})$.

There are multiple values of this, but the *principal value* is when $k = 1$, which gives the value of the expression as $2 \cos(6\pi/7) = -2 \cos(\pi/7)$.

Comment: If you don't understand, you will have to learn complex numbers. One resource to start with is [here](https://www.mathonweb.com/help_ebook/html/complex_2.htm).

Comment: Hmmm, so $a^{2033}+\frac{1}{a^{2033}}$ is?

Comment: Sorry for the typo: $a \ne -2 \cos(\pi/7)$ but the answer is $-2 \cos(\pi/7)$.

Comment: Can you explain where $a=e^{2 \pi ki/7}$ from?

Comment: i now, i've read on wikipedia

Comment: I recommend you read [the link](https://www.mathonweb.com/help_ebook/html/complex_2.htm) I gave you first. Then learn [Euler's formula](https://brilliant.org/wiki/eulers-formula/), and substitute $x = 2 \pi$ in there. To try the quizzes on that website you will need to register.

Comment: Thanks @TobyMak

Comment: No problem again, sama-sama.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $P(a)-2020=0$, and notice that $P(x)-2020=325\Phi_7(x)$ where $\Phi_7(x):=x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is the $7$-th Cyclotomic polynomial. Now use facts about the roots of $\Phi_7(x)$, in particular these are primitive $7$-th roots of unity.

Comment: I have no idea!

Comment: Where is this question from? You're in junior high school, so please add that information to the *question*, otherwise you will get answers that you will not understand.

Comment: See [how to prevent no clue questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27923/how-to-prevent-no-clue-questions) and [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to learn how you can ask a better question next time.

Comment: @TobyMak Thanks for your warning

Comment: @AllifQalbiy No problem! I'm writing an answer now.